# Javascript function return object which contains 3 function defination but IntelliSense is not working for that return type

Tags: javascript, closures

I have written a Logger function in javascript and that is a singleton function, from that function I am returning an object that contains the definition of the two functions, So when I am creating an object of that class I get the returned object contains function definition, and when I want to call something on that returned value my code IntelliSense is not working, can anybody help me with the IntelliSense. Also sharing the code. I am getting the IntelliSense for the **getInstance** method, but when i wan to use **obj.setDebug** I am not getting any code suggestion or IntelliSense for that part.

[image]

> That Obj.isDebug autocomplete i am not getting

```
const Logger = () => {
  let instance = null
  _isDebug = false

  let setDebug = (value = false) => {
    _isDebug = value
  }

  let isDebug = () => {
    return _isDebug
  }

  createInstance = () => ({
    setDebug,
    isDebug,
    log
  })

  return {
    getInstance: () => {
      if (!instance) {
        instance = createInstance()
      }
      return instance
    }
  }
}

const Log = Logger()
const obj = Log.getInstance();

console.log(obj.setDebug())
console.log(obj.isDebug())
```

Comment: When you use ``obj.setDebug``, nothing is returned, of course, only undefined is printed

Comment: @Jinweizhu i was talking about autocomplete for obj once i press .s i should get obj.setDebut i am not talking about returned value or print value. how can i get the intellisense with that obj.

Comment: What editor, what intellisense implementation are you using?

Comment: This internal `_instance` and the `getInstance` methods are totally overcomplicated. Why not just return the instance from the `Logger()` factory directly?

Comment: @Bergi i am trying to achieve Singleton design pattern with that return pattern, cannot return a new instance each time someone calls a function

Comment: @abankitbaid But you already do that, `Logger` is not a singleton.

Comment: @Bergi yes it is, From this file i am exporting **Log**. So how many time you call Log.getInstance() in any files you will get the same instance. And as far as i know thats the singleton behaviour

Comment: @abankitbaid If you're only exporting `Log` and call `Logger` only once, why define `Logger` at all? Just omit it and write `const Log = { getInstance() { … } };`. Or use an IIFE to make your intention clear.

Comment: @Bergi thats the same thing. making it an IIFE or calling it once for Log = Logger()

Answer (score 0):

Do `getInstance` automatically while defining `Log`, it'll be more simple:

```
const Logger = () => {
  // Set app
  const app = {
    // Set _isDebug option
    _isDebug: false,
    // Set setDebug method
    setDebug: (value = false) => app._isDebug = value,
    // Get isDebug method
    isDebug: (value = false) => app._isDebug
  };
  
  return app;
}

const Log = Logger();

Log.setDebug(true);
console.log(Log.isDebug());
```

Example [is here](https://jsbin.com/secidan/17/edit?js,console)

If you need more complex function with separate `getInstance` method, just follow the logic and feel free to add as much additional layers as you need... Below code is just for example. In given context it is pointless as I've mentioned before:

```
const Logger = () => {
  // Set app
  const app = {
    // Set _isDebug option
    _isDebug: false,
    // Set isDebug method
    setDebug: (value = false) => app._isDebug = value,
    // Get isDebug method
    isDebug: (value = false) => app._isDebug
  };
  
  // Initiator
  const initiator = {
    // Set init status var
    instance: false,
    // Set getInstance method
    getInstance: () => {
      if(!initiator.instance) initiator.instance = app;
      return initiator.instance;
    }
  }
  
  return initiator;
}

const Log = Logger();
const obj = Log.getInstance();

obj.setDebug(true);
console.log(obj.isDebug());
```

Example [is here](https://jsbin.com/gurapig/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: i have edited my question, i am talking about the autocomplete for **obj.isDebug()** once i type **obj.** i should get isDebug, setDebug in autocomplete. Because of closuer i am not getting the deep autocomplete. Any idea bout about that